# How the sentence below isn't a run-on sentence?

Tags: punctuation, commas, sentence, comma-splices

**A wire brush periodically swept the cotton off the blade and prevented the machine from jamming.**

Shouldn't the sentence be like this?

**A wire brush periodically swept the cotton off the *blade, and* prevented the machine from jamming.**

Answer (score 1):

No. In this case, you're joining two concepts that are dependent upon one another.

We have the **wire brush**. It sweeps cotton off the blade **which** prevents the machine from jamming. The latter is dependent on the former. It wouldn't make as much sense to merely say the wire brush prevented the machine from jamming. This is a [coordinating conjunction](https://writing.wisc.edu/handbook/grammarpunct/coordconj/). You would need a comma if we had something independent (i.e. not related to the wire brush)

> A wire brush periodically swept the cotton off the blade, and a blower would mix the cotton.

This is now a run-on sentence because the blower and it's action are *independent* of the function and purpose of the wire brush. The hallmark of this is that we can easily break this into two sentences. [This page has another illustration](https://examples.yourdictionary.com/comma-splice-examples.html)

> She took the boy's cookies away and that was mean.

Once again, we see the part about *being mean* is dependent upon the first clause.